# Edit option is available after 5 minutes

Tags: discussion, bug

I have commented in some question and I discovered that **edit** option is available after 5 minutes.

[image]

And, when I **clicked** on edit option, it showed textbox also.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really a bug, so much as the fact that the page doesn't check the timestamp/edit status to remove the edit link until you refresh the page or actually attempt to submit the comment.

So, yes, you can type in a comment edit but if you actually try to submit it, it would fail to go through. I've had this happen before, so there's no "exploit".

It is somewhat deceptive but it might be a bit expensive to track this for comments to live update. I suppose they could additionally run the check when clicking on "edit" as on "submit" but they'd have to both because you could start the edit at 4:45 and take over 15 seconds to submit it and then that would be a problem.

Comment: Oh, I had not tried to submit it :P

Comment: The comment timer is *already* updated dynamically, so it should have no impact on the server and should be a negligible performance impact on the client to just have some `if (time >= 5 min) disable` code. I wouldn't recommend hiding the link dynamically for a few reasons, but simply disabling it (and the Save button) should be simple enough.